# PowerShell: Receiving error "The term '...' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have big problem when trying to execute a PowerShell function which is in another file.

This is my initial .ps1 file:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

$file = Get-Item $scriptDir\JSONFile1.json
$plaintext = $file | Get-Content

.\Functions\Add-Folder.ps1 -AdlsAccountName "Hello World"
```

The file `Add-Folder.ps1` consists of the following content:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string] $AdlsAccountName
)

Write-Host $AdlsAccountName
```

But when i execute this .ps1 script i receive the following error:

`##[error]The term '.\Add-Folder.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add dot when you referencing files:

```
. .\Functions\Add-Folder.ps1 -AdlsAccountName "Hello World"
```

This technique named dot sourcing.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts

https://ss64.com/ps/source.html

Comment: No doesnt work. How can i extend this to add a dedicated folder where this fie `add-folder.ps1` resides? I mean not only `.\functions\add-folder.ps1` instead having something like `'c:\my files\add-folder.ps1 -parameter`. But i dont know the correct syntaxy and even if this is possible?

Comment: Check this screenshot - https://imgur.com/FRrPosR
It just works as expected. Could you elaborate what exactly doesn't work for you?